# 425 Unable to build data connection FileZilla, using windows 11 FTP command

Tags: command-line, ftp

sorry for constantly asking for advice.

I am trying to download files from my FileZilla server using the cmd command `ftp`

This does indeed work, when the ports are set to 21 i can access the server and download files.

Yet when i change the port to 80, i cannot anymore, it does establish the connection but doesn do anything except error 425 after sending the `get` command.

port 80 and 21 are both open in the router and in FileZilla

no firewall

Answer (score 5, accepted):

FTP uses separate "control" and "data" connections. Port 21 is only for control – each data transfer (including a directory listing) is a new connection on a *new,* temporary pair of ports. Those ports must be open in the firewall and appropriately "port-forwarded" if behind NAT.

Most home routers and firewalls have **special treatment for port 21** – the router snoops on the control commands that are used to open the FTP data channels (i.e. the `PORT`/`EPRT` and `PASV`/`EPSV` commands) and *automatically* creates temporary firewall rules for the data transfer ports mentioned therein.

This is especially important for "active mode" (the default for ftp.exe) as the data connections are backwards, i.e. from FTP server to client, so with the client being under NAT there *must* be port-forwarding rules for them.

Additionally, these commands indicate the (client's or server's) IP address to connect to, so your router might also attempt to rewrite the commands in-flight so that they refer to your external IP instead of the internal one.

When the same commands are being sent over other ports, however, the rewriting *is not* done – the firewall remains closed and no port-forwarding rules are set up. (The router does not recognize FTP just because it "looks like FTP"; there are quite a few protocols that look *a lot like* FTP.)

---

If your router has an "ALG" ("Application Layer Gateway") section or a "L7 protocol" section, it might be possible to change which ports are handled as "FTP ports".

For passive mode, the ports can be defined statically on the server side. Generally if you are setting up an FTP server at home, you should configure it to use a specific "passive port" range (e.g. 50000-50999) and *manually* create a port-forwarding rule on your router for that entire range. This will make the FTP server work on any control port, as long as clients use passive mode.

However, active mode needs such configuration and port-forwarding to be done on the *client* side instead. Many FTP clients, similarly, let you choose which ports to use for active mode; but I don't think ftp.exe has such an option either.

In conclusion, you probably should use a different FTP client, e.g. `winscp.com` from WinSCP if you need a Windows CLI (I'd have suggested lftp as well but it seems to lack Windows builds), make sure it is set to *passive* mode, and configure the FTP server to have a static port range for passive transfers.

*(Well, generally, you shouldn't be setting up FTP servers in this day and age; you should be using SFTP or something else – or at least setting up a simple VPN to use the FTP server with, not just for security but also to avoid the whole PORT/PASV issue.)*

Comment: i cannot unfortunatly use the PASV command since i am using the windows ftp, my routr also does not have a l7 protocol or ALG section as you suggested, i do have virtual server and port forwarding, if that is what you mean (i am not good with long explenations or instructions, my mind automatical summarises the information i receive and does it very poorly when theres too much info or complex words)

Comment: @NeatPace: Then you're probably out of luck, and you need to switch to a different FTP client. With active mode, it's the router on the _client_ side that needs this configuration (as the "active" data connections are made from FTP server to client), and even if you could make it work e.g. when connecting from home, it's not realistic to expect that it would work from everywhere. It's why passive mode was created.

Answer (score 1):

"Virtual server" is in some routers another name for
[port-forwarding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Port_forwarding).

In port-forwarding, there are two ports that are involved :

- The port you wish to open in your router to the public
- The port to which you wish to forward the outside connection
  on the computer that is indicated by its IP in the local network.

In your case, the first one should be 80 but the internal one should
stay 21.

This disguises it from the outside world, but keeps the
functionality. Otherwise, you would also need to configure
Filezilla to use the other port.

Comment: indeed, this is what i have done, yet in my router port forwarding and virtual server are different options, i believe i have set them up correctly, since it has worked when using port 21, in the public ip i changed it to 80 and now it somehow doesnt work